# Generalizing a theorem about filters on a boolean lattice

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, filters

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a bounded distributive lattice with binary meet and join $\sqcap$ and $\sqcup$.

I will denote $\partial F = \{ X\in\mathfrak{A} \mid \forall Y\in F: X\sqcap Y\ne \bot \}$ where $F$ is a filter on $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\bot$ is the least element of the lattice.

I will say that *the set of filters is star-separable* iff $A\ne B$ implies $\partial A \ne \partial B$ for every filters $A$ and $B$.

I [my draft book](http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html) it is proved that the set of filters on a boolean lattice is star-separable.

Can this result be strengthened? Particularly, is it true for all bounded distributive lattices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true for all bounded distributive lattices.  Consider the distributive lattice $\bot \to a \to \top$ and the filters $\uparrow{a}$ and $\{\top\}$.

Comment: Hm, maybe it holds for all complemented lattices?

Comment: nope, it does not hold for all complemented lattices.

Comment: Maybe, it holds for all Heyting or all co-Heyting lattices?

Comment: Nope.  It does not hold for all heyting and co-heyting algebras.  Just check the example in the answer :)